# Procedure SQLDeveloper - Obtener tabla 'DBA_USERS'

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy queriendo crear un procedimiento para que SQLDeveloper me muestre, en la salida de DBMS, si existe, o no, un nombre de usuario. el nombre de usuario se pasaría mediante parámetros.
El problema es el siguiente, al ejecutar el statement el log devuelve lo siguiente:

> Error(5,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored.
>
> Error(7,10): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: la tabla o vista no existe.

El código es el siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CONSULTAR_EXISTENCIA_USUARIO (USER VARCHAR2)
IS
    USEREXISTANCE INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO USEREXISTANCE
    FROM DBA_USERS
    WHERE USERNAME LIKE USER;
    IF (USEREXISTANCE = 0) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO EXISTE EL USUARIO');
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EL USUARIO EXISTE');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: DBA_USERS es una tabla a la que sólo tienes acceso con usuarios con privilegios (como SYS, SYSTEM). Con qué usuario intentas consultarla?

Comment: Si ejecuto el statement de forma normal me deja, el problema es cuando lo convierto en un procedure. Lo ejecuto con SYSTEM

Comment: Con qué usuario **creas** el procedimiento, en qué esquema queda?

Answer (score 0):

Para compilar un objeto PL/SQL que utilice una de las tablas del sistema (DBA_%) se requiere que con el usuario SYS o SYSTEM se otorgue explícitamente el privilegio SELECT sobre esa tabla al usuario donde va a residir el procedimiento.